# How to redirect to https in Apache2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ssl, apache2

We are hosting magento site in AWS. I configured SSL using certbot and it automatically created conf file. But when I am trying to hit the URL. It is showing `too many attempts`. Below are the Apache2 configuration files.

**mysite.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magento
        <Directory /var/www/html/magento>
                Allowoverride All
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [OR]
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

**mysite-ssl.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerName example.com
                ServerAlias www.example.com
                DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magento
                <Directory /var/www/html/magento>
                        Allowoverride All
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

                SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
                Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

In Magento, I changed config_url to `https://example.com`

**Error**

```
This page isn’t working
mysite.com redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart apache? It seems like you're hitting VHOST on port 80 and redirecting constantly.

Comment: yes I restarted the apache, still no result it is showing too many ```ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS```

Comment: Looked in apache error log and access log to validate whats happening under the hood?